# Raspberry pi and nextion touch screen communication using python

Tags: python, serial, touchscreen, uart

I have tested several python codes to set up the communication between raspberry pi and nextion touch screen (I used TTL serial GPIO 14 and 15). Unfortunately, the communication is not stable, the manufacturer of this screen provides several libraries for C++, but there is not much support for python. I want to know if there is anyone who has used this screen with the raspberry pi and gets stable communication using python?
[image]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `communication is not stable`

Comment: mean that I didn't get the same data sent from screen to raspberry or from raspberry to screen (example: when I press a button on screen the screen sent a hexadecimal number such as 65 00 01 01 FF FF FF to raspberry but in reception, I get a random value )

Comment: please add that to the question ... also add an example of the data that is actually received

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in Python3 on Raspberry PI4 and Nextion 10" display.

```
port = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate =9600,           
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)
```

Also important to use correct EOF [End of File] you need three after each "write"
e.g.,

```
eof = struct.pack('B', 0xff)
 
port.write("page 0".encode())
port.write(eof)
port.write(eof)
port.write(eof)
```